# How can I use jQuery in a native String prototypal function?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I would like to know how I could use `jQuery` inside a native prototype function of the `String` object for instance.

I've tried:

```
String.prototype.jQ = function() {
    var $currentObject = $( this );

    return ( $currentObject.length ) ? $currentObject.val() : this;
};

var test = "#txtEmail";
alert( test.jQ() );
```

With no luck. Any suggestion?

I am perfectly aware that I could use `$( test ).val()` but I would like to know if I can do it my way.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea. +1, good question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, jQuery only accepts primitive string values as selectors, not String objects, which is what `this` is in a `String` prototype method. You can use `.valueOf()` to get the primitive:

```
String.prototype.jQ = function() {
    var $currentObject = $(this.valueOf());

    return $currentObject.length ? $currentObject.val() : this;
};
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/LU76c/)

Answer (score 1):

$( this + ""); // because "this" is currently an array of characters

```
String.prototype.jQ = function() {
    var $currentObject = $( this + "");

    return ( $currentObject.length ) ? $currentObject.val() : this;
};

var test = "#txtEmail";
alert( test.jQ() );
```

Comment: Your answer is also very good but since minitech have provided a demo link, I will accept his answer.